# Spark UDF called more than once per record when DF has too many columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.6.1 and encountering a strange behaviour: I'm running an UDF with some heavy computations (a physics simulations) on a dataframe containing some input data, and building up a result-Dataframe containing many columns (~40).

Strangely, my UDF is called more than once per Record of my input Dataframe in this case (1.6 times more often), which I find unacceptable because its very expensive. If I reduce the number of columns (e.g. to 20), then this behavior disappears.

I managed to write down a small script which demonstrates this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


object Demo {

  case class Result(a: Double)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Demo").setMaster("local[*]"))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val numRuns = sc.accumulator(0) // to count the number of udf calls

    val myUdf = udf((i:Int) => {numRuns.add(1);Result(i.toDouble)})

    val data = sc.parallelize((1 to 100), numSlices = 5).toDF("id")

    // get results of UDF
    var results = data
      .withColumn("tmp", myUdf($"id"))
      .withColumn("result", $"tmp.a")


    // add many columns to dataframe (must depend on the UDF's result)
    for (i <- 1 to 42) {
      results=results.withColumn(s"col_$i",$"result")
    }

    // trigger action
    val res = results.collect()
    println(res.size) // prints 100

    println(numRuns.value) // prints 160

  }
}
```

Now, is there a way to solve this without reducing the number of columns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't really explain this behavior - but obviously the query plan somehow chooses a path where some of the records are calculated twice. This means that if we **cache** the intermediate result (right after applying the UDF) we might be able to "force" Spark not to recompute the UDF. And indeed, once caching is added it behaves as expected - UDF is called exactly 100 times:

```
// get results of UDF
var results = data
  .withColumn("tmp", myUdf($"id"))
  .withColumn("result", $"tmp.a").cache()
```

Of course, caching has its own costs (memory...), but it might end up beneficial in your case if it saves many UDF calls.

Comment: This actually works! I still wait with accepting the answer, maybe someone has a comprehensive answer

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious too - perfectly OK with you not accepting :)

Answer (score 9):

We had this same problem about a year ago and spent a lot of time till we finally figured out what was the problem.

We also had a very expensive UDF to calculate and we found out that it gets calculated again and again for every time we refer to its column. Its just happened to us again a few days ago, so I decided to open a bug on this:
[SPARK-18748](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18748)

We also opened a question here then, but now I see the title wasn't so good:
[Trying to turn a blob into multiple columns in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587596/trying-to-turn-a-blob-into-multiple-columns-in-spark/)

I agree with Tzach about somehow "forcing" the plan to calculate the UDF. We did it uglier, but we had to, because we couldn't cache() the data - it was too big:

```
val df = data.withColumn("tmp", myUdf($"id"))
val results = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
             .withColumn("result", $"tmp.a")
```

update:

Now I see that my jira ticket was linked to another one: [SPARK-17728](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17728), which still didn't really handle this issue the right way, but it gives one more optional work around:

```
val results = data.withColumn("tmp", explode(array(myUdf($"id"))))
                  .withColumn("result", $"tmp.a")
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer spark verion (2.3+) we can mark UDFs as non-deterministic: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.html#asNondeterministic():org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

i.e. use

```
val myUdf = udf(...).asNondeterministic()
```

This makes sure the UDF is only called once