# spark sql use createOrReplaceTempView not really compute the result?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My code is like this:

```
dataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName1")
//udf1 and udf2 will return a struct
var dataFrame1 = sql("select udf1(a) as col1,udf2(a) as col2 from tableName1");
dataFrame1.createOrReplaceTempView("tableName2")
var dataFrame2 = sql("select col1.x,col1.y,col1.z,col2.x,col2.y,col2.z from tableName2");
dataFrame2.write.parquet("path")
```

I see the physical plan in Spark UI is like this:

```
select udf1(a).x,udf1(a).y,udf1(a).z,udf2.x,udf2.y,udf2.z from tableName2
```

It seems like that the `udf1` and `udf2` will be invoked 3 times。
What I really want is that `udf1` and `udf2` only compute once。
Hope some can help me.

Comment: I don't think that the udf is called 3 times. I would use an LongAccumulator to count then UDF calls directly and then compare with the number of rows in your dataframe

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I add a log in the udf1. when I run this sql, every row have 3 logs of udf1.

Comment: it's possible that the udf is really computed more than once, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320563/spark-udf-called-more-than-once-per-record-when-df-has-too-many-columns, You could try to influence the optimizer, e.g. by caching dataFrame1: `var dataFrame1 = sql("select udf1(a) as col1,udf2(a) as col2 from tableName1").cache();`