# SPARK 3 - Populate value with value from previous rows (lookup)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark3

I am new to SPARK.  I have 2 dataframes `events` and `players`

events dataframe consists of columns

`event_id| player_id| match_id| impact_score`

players dataframe consists of columns

`player_id| player_name| nationality`

I am merging the two datasets by `player_id` with this query:

```
df_final = (events
  .orderBy("player_id") 
  .join(players.orderBy("player_id"))
  .withColumn("current_team", when([no idea what goes in here]).otherwise(getCurrentTeam(col("player_id"))))
  .write.mode("overwrite")
  .partitionBy("current_team")
)
```

`getCurrentTeam` function triggers an HTTP call that returns a value (player's current team).

I have data of over 30 million soccer plays and 97 players. I need help creating column `current_team`.  Imagine certain player appearing 130,000 times in events dataframe.  I need to lookup values from previous rows.  If player appears, I just grab that value (like an in-memory catalog).  If it does not appear, then I call the webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to it's distributed nature, Spark can't allow for if allow populated in previous call then use it otherwise call created value. There are two possible options.

1. Since you are applying an inner join and `players` df has the list of all distinct players, you can add the `current_team` column to this df before applying a join. If the `players` df is cached before joining then it's possible that the `UDF` is invoked only once for each player. See discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320563/spark-udf-called-more-than-once-per-record-when-df-has-too-many-columns) for why UDF can be called multiple time for each record.
2. You can [memoize](https://dbader.org/blog/python-memoization)  `getCurrentTeam`

## Working Example - Prepopulate `current_team`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

events_data = [(1, 1, 1, 10), (1, 2, 1, 20, ), (1, 3, 1, 30, ), (2, 3, 1, 30, ), (2, 1, 1, 10), (2, 2, 1, 20, ), ]
players_data = [(1, "Player1", "Nat", ), (2, "Player2", "Nat", ), (3, "Player3", "Nat", ), ]

events = spark.createDataFrame(events_data, ("event_id", "player_id", "match_id", "impact_score", ), ).repartition(3)
players = spark.createDataFrame(players_data, ("player_id", "player_name", "nationality", ), ).repartition(3)


@udf(StringType())
def getCurrentTeam(player_id):
    return f"player_{player_id}_team"

players_with_current_team = players.withColumn("current_team", getCurrentTeam(F.col("player_id"))).cache()

events.join(players_with_current_team, ["player_id"]).show()
```

### Output

```py
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|player_id|event_id|match_id|impact_score|player_name|nationality| current_team|
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|        2|       2|       1|          20|    Player2|        Nat|player_2_team|
|        2|       1|       1|          20|    Player2|        Nat|player_2_team|
|        3|       2|       1|          30|    Player3|        Nat|player_3_team|
|        3|       1|       1|          30|    Player3|        Nat|player_3_team|
|        1|       2|       1|          10|    Player1|        Nat|player_1_team|
|        1|       1|       1|          10|    Player1|        Nat|player_1_team|
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

## Working Example - Memoization

I have used a python dict for mimicing caching and using an [`accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.Accumulator.html) to count number of mimicked network calls made.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
import time

events_data = [(1, 1, 1, 10), (1, 2, 1, 20, ), (1, 3, 1, 30, ), (2, 3, 1, 30, ), (2, 1, 1, 10), (2, 2, 1, 20, ), ]
players_data = [(1, "Player1", "Nat", ), (2, "Player2", "Nat", ), (3, "Player3", "Nat", ), ]

events = spark.createDataFrame(events_data, ("event_id", "player_id", "match_id", "impact_score", ), ).repartition(3)
players = spark.createDataFrame(players_data, ("player_id", "player_name", "nationality", ), ).repartition(3)

players_events_joined = events.join(players, ["player_id"])

memoized_call_counter = spark.sparkContext.accumulator(0)
def memoize_call():
    cache = {}
    def getCurrentTeam(player_id):
        global memoized_call_counter
        cached_value = cache.get(player_id, None)
        if cached_value is not None:
            return cached_value
        # sleep to mimic network call
        time.sleep(1)
        # Increment counter everytime cached value can't be lookedup
        memoized_call_counter.add(1)
        cache[player_id] = f"player_{player_id}_team"
        return cache[player_id]
    return getCurrentTeam
    
getCurrentTeam_udf = udf(memoize_call(), StringType())

players_events_joined.withColumn("current_team", getCurrentTeam_udf(F.col("player_id"))).show()
```

### Output

```py
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|player_id|event_id|match_id|impact_score|player_name|nationality| current_team|
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|        2|       2|       1|          20|    Player2|        Nat|player_2_team|
|        2|       1|       1|          20|    Player2|        Nat|player_2_team|
|        3|       2|       1|          30|    Player3|        Nat|player_3_team|
|        3|       1|       1|          30|    Player3|        Nat|player_3_team|
|        1|       2|       1|          10|    Player1|        Nat|player_1_team|
|        1|       1|       1|          10|    Player1|        Nat|player_1_team|
+---------+--------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

```py
>>> memoized_call_counter.value
3
```

> Since there are 3 unique players in total the logic after `time.sleep(1)` was called only thrice. The number of calls is dependent on the number of workers, since the cache is not shared across workers. As I ran the example in local mode (wuth 1 worker) we see that the number of calls is equal to number of workers.