# Exceeding the limit of Apache Spark UDFs [UDF_MAX_COUNT_EXCEEDED]

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks

I'm working on a dataproject in Azure Databricks and need to define a UDF:

```python
@udf(returnType=IntegerType()) 
def ends_with_one(value, bit_position): 
    if bit_position + len(value) < 0: 
        return 0
    else: 
        return int(value[bit_position] == '1') 

spark.udf.register("ends_with_one", ends_with_one)
```

But somehow instead of registering the UDF once, it get's registered every time I call it:

```python
df = df.withColumn('Ends_With_One', ends_with_one(col('Column_To_Check'), lit(-1)))
```

And after a few function calls I get the following error message:

```
[UDF_MAX_COUNT_EXCEEDED] Exceeded query-wide UDF limit of 5 UDFs (limited during public preview). Found 6. The UDFs were: `ends_with_one`,`ends_with_one`,`ends_with_one`,`ends_with_one`,`ends_with_one`,`ends_with_one`.
```

I thought maybe it could have something to do with Sparks lazy evaluation so i called

```python
display(df)
```

right after the function calls because I had a lot of code without actually executing it. But this didn't solve anything. I also tried

```python
df('ends_with_one', ends_with_one(col('Column_To_Check'), lit(-1))).rdd.count
```

to force an execution but still the same error message.

Comment: Does changing the spark.databricks.safespark.externalUDF.plan.limit setting resolve the issue for you? See https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/udf-max-count-exceeded-exceeded-query-wide-udf-limit-of-5-udfs/m-p/38170#M26569.

Comment: I saw this thread and yes I already changed the limit to 10 but after some extra code this limit was exceeded aswell. So this doesn't help. The main problem is, that I registered my UDF once, but the error message says I did register it 6 or even more times.

Comment: It's not clear to me that "exceeded query-wide UDF limit" indicates you registered the function too many times. It could also just be calling it too many times.

Comment: You can use `spark.catalog.listFunctions()` to check this - I imagine you'll still only see one registration of "ends_with_one".

Comment: I can't access the method because of my cluster mode, but if as you supposed  there is only one function and I'm just calling it too many times, what can I do about it? @PhilipDakin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently in some cases Spark calls a UDF more than one time per call. Especially when you are referring to a certain column that you generated/edited with a UDF the UDF calls get more and more. Thanks to this thread ([Spark UDF called more than once per record when DF has too many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320563/spark-udf-called-more-than-once-per-record-when-df-has-too-many-columns)), I found a workaround. Since Spark 2.3 and newer there is a function provided for non-deterministic UDFs.

```
val myUdf = udf(...).asNondeterministic()
```

This makes sure the UDF is only called once.